# Change of @angular/ui-router from full state name to simple

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a three tier view setup with angular ui router. I used to do:

```
 <a ui-sref="global.nav.dashboard">GO</a>
```

but now, even though I have the same setup, in Angular 4 its:

`<a uiSref="dashboard">GO</a>`?  I don't need to fully qualify the parents anymore?

Comment: there is no difference between how `@uirouter/angular` and `@uirouter/angularjs` handles this.  Are you perhaps using `parent:` now?

Comment: yes, I started using parent: instead of doing global.nav.foo as the name. It used to bark at me if I used a ui-sref that wasn't registered - it seems to allow those now?